# Transferring values from one worksheet to another using If, Then And Statement

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement, variable-assignment

In writing this code I am coming up with a invalid next variable reference. What am I doing wrong?
My intent is to place values from one worksheet into another given a cell's value or string id.

```
Dim Rev_2, Sch, vet                  As Worksheet
Dim i, Row, RowNum                   As Long
Dim FRow, FirstRow, lastRow, LRow    As Integer

FirstRow = 4
FRow = 4
lastRow = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Rev_2").Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LRow = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Vet Raw Data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
On Error Resume Next
Set Sch = Worksheets("Rev_2")
Set vet = Worksheets("Vet Raw Data")
MsgBox (lastRow)
MsgBox (LRow)
LRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For RowNum = FirstRow To lastRow
    For Row = FRow To LRow
        If Sheets("Rev_2").Cells(RowNum, 16).Value = "MACH_SHOP" Then Sheets("Vet Raw Data").Cells(Row, 11).Value = Sheets("Rev_2").Cells(RowNum, 14).Value And Sheets("Vet Raw Data").Cells(Row, 39).Value = Sheets("Rev_2").Cells(RowNum, 15).Value
    Next RowNum
Next Row
End Sub
```

Comment: `Next Row` should precede `Next RowNum`. Indenting your code properly helps with this kind of problem (see my edit to your question)

Comment: Your variable declarations are incorrect. Remove the on error line. Then tell us which line is causing the problem and what the error is.

Comment: As requested I removed the "On Error Resume Next" line.  It will run but does not produce any output in the sheet that I'd expect.

Comment: If I do follow and proceed with the Next Row before the Next RowNum. I'm only trying to pull data out of the Vet Raw Data into the Rev_2 worksheet.  Going with RowNum first generates an error that the next control variable reference is invalid.

Comment: `If Sheets("Rev_2").Cells(RowNum, 16).Value = "MACH_SHOP" Then` i.e. `If Sch.Cells(RowNum, 16).Value = "MACH_SHOP" Then` probably needs to go between the *For* lines because it doesn't depend on `Row`. The **rest of the line** needs some clarifications e.g. it could be something like `If vet.Cells(Row, 11).Value = Sch.Cells(RowNum, 14).Value Then` : `vet.Cells(Row, 39).Value = Sch.Cells(RowNum, 15).Value` : `End If` : `Next Row` : `End If` : `Next RowNum` but we can't be sure. Please explain which additional condition should force the code to write what and where (use columns to explain).